# LED Music Visualizer on Headphones

Tags: led, music

I am currently trying to make an LED music visualizer that goes to music and attaches to my headphones. The ideal solution would be to have the LEDs run from the audio circuit from a smartphone (with a battery I would charge adding extra power), but I have also considered drilling a hole through my over-the-ear headphones for a small mic. So far, I haven't had that much luck, but I stumbled upon this circuit diagram:[image]

This seems to solve some of my problems but I can't figure out whether it analyzes each frequency or if all the LEDs would bounce at once. My main question, though, is how I would use this and my heap homes at the same time. Should I use a splitter to get two audio signals? Is there a way I could add more power and connect the headphones through this circuit to still hear music? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit does not appear to have any frequency sensitive components, instead each successive transistor will be a little less sensitive to the incoming signal because of the diode drops, so the effect will be more like a saturating VU meter.

What you want is a circuit like this one:

[image]

which has three frequency bands (low, middle, high). It is designed to run off a 9v battery, like your other circuit.